# Some python date manipulation

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to Python. I need two functions. The first is supposed to get the current date and then return the starting and ending dates of that month e.g if current date is 02/12/2012, it should return 02/01/2012 and 02/29/2012. The second function does something similar but instead returns the beginning & ending dates of the previous month. Please how can I do that in Python?  Thanks in anticipation

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Agreed. This is a blatant 'do it for me' and shows a complete lack of effort. Show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK -- I'm bored.

First, unless you are from Mars or somewhere, we here on Earth begin every month with `1`. Safe assumption.

The only challenging part is the number of days in the month. You can get that from [calendar.monthrange()](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange)

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2012,2)
(2, 29)
```

The second number there is the ending day of that month in that year. So you can do:

```
import calendar
import datetime

def mSandE(yy,mm):
    lastDay=calendar.monthrange(yy,mm)[1]
    dt1=datetime.date(yy, mm, 1)
    dt2=datetime.date(yy, mm, lastDay)
    return (dt1, dt2)

def prevmSandE(yy,mm):
    dt=mSandE(yy,mm)[0]
    dt=dt-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    lastDay=calendar.monthrange(dt.year,dt.month)[1]
    return (dt.replace(day=1),datetime.date(dt.year,dt.month,lastDay))


print mSandE(2012,2)        
print prevmSandE(2012,2)
print prevmSandE(2012,1)
```

Prints:

```
(datetime.date(2012, 2, 1), datetime.date(2012, 2, 29))
(datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), datetime.date(2012, 1, 31))
(datetime.date(2011, 12, 1), datetime.date(2011, 12, 31))
```